# Apache camel Restlet and swagger integration example

Tags: rest, spring-boot, apache-camel, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using Apache camel and Spring boot and Rest service, we are exposing the rest service with Restlet component. Now I want to generate the API documentation using Swagger.

So I found two ways,
1) Add dependency and swagger config changes.
2) Create specification and invoke the developed service.

In both the ways I could not find any example with Restllet component. With restConfiguration() configuration its working, I want to do it with Restlet.

I have created specification in yaml and invoking the service, Service exposed using "restlet:http://0.0.0.0:8090/path?restletMethod=post" URI.

I am getting below error,

OPTIONS "http://127.0.0.1:8090/path" 500 (Internal Server Error)
Fetch API cannot load "http://127.0.0.1:8090/path". Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

with the swagger specification can we invoke camel Restlet? if yes, what is the approach?

Comment: Can you be more clear what you want? Are you saying that you do NOT want to use rest-dsl but just camel-restlet and plain Camel routes, and _somehow_ have swagger specification created automatic, or what?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to use rest-dsl. I have created specification using swagger editor with this I need to invoke the service api  which is already developed by using camel restlet. without changing the service.

Comment: Well you get a HTTP error 500 which is a server side error, so try to look at its log what is the error. The camel-restlet component is using Restlet library and it can do what Restlet supports, so it ought to be able to call REST services.